# Model Validation on InlineAdmin in Django

Tags: django

Within an app for an online shop I have two simple models for products and deliveries:

```
class Product(model.models):
    delivery = models.ForeignKey(Delivery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Delivery(model.models):
   published = models.Datefield()
```

**I am using the build-in Django admin.**

```
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product

@admin.register(Delivery)
class DeliveryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductInline,]
```

To increase robustness of the app it is very important, **that products can't be changed as soon as the related delivery has been published to the customer.** So on very attempt to change a product, I need to do some validation to check if the Delivery has been published. Things I have tried:

- Create `fieldset` for InlineAdmin with custom `clean()`method
- Custom `clean()` method on the model instance

These approaches don't work, though. When implemented, I loose the ability to edit the entire delivery model from the admin panel (I am trying to only limit edits of products). This is because clicking the save Button in the admin Panel will automatically call `save()` and `clean()` on the products regardless of weather or not the products were changed.

Has someone encountered a similar problem before?

Comment: I think that the easiest way would be to override the `save()` method. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading

Comment: thank you, that was helpful. Raising the error from the save() method will crash quite hard resulting in an error screen. Do you happen to know the correct method to overwrite in the admin to catch the error from admin?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to override the form?

```
class ProductInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        # your validation. 
        # here you can raise ValidationError
        return super().clean()

class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ProductInlineForm
    model = Product
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: I am pretty sure, that the TabularInline is not a ModelForm but a Formset. As you can read above, I already tried to overwrite the clean() method for the Formset. Also it would not make a difference in this case since the SAVE-Button in the admin for Delivery would trigger the clean() validation for the products making me unable to edit the delivery model from the admin.

Comment: If you override form for TabularInline, clean will validate the instance of Product. And then if self.instance.delivery.published is not None you can raise error. Sorry, if I midunderstood you.